# Looping through a directory retaining the file name (without extension) in the output (kracken2)

Tags: linux, bash, loops, for-loop, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to loop kraken2 through a directory full of .fastq.gz files

e.g.

- file1.fastq.gz
- file2.fastq.gz
- file3.fastq.gz
- ...
- fileN.fastq.gz

using

```
for FILE in path/to/fastq/files/directory/*
do 
OUT=$(basename $FILE) kraken2 --db path/to/16S_SILVA138_k2db --threads 12 --use-names --gzip-compressed ${FILE} --output path/to/output/directory/${OUT}_kraken.txt --report path/to/output/directory/${OUT}_report.txt 
done
```

I would like to have a kracken output file and a report file for each sample individually
e.g.

- file1_kracken.txt
- file1.report.txt
- ...
- fileN.report.txt
- fileN.report.txt

However, the only results Im getting in the output folder are two files (not two for each sample, two lonely files) named

> _kraken.txt

and

> _report.txt

For sure Im doing something wrong when setting up the loop and with OUT=$(basename $FILE)...
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

MW

Comment: Use a separate line for the assignment `OUT=$(basename "$FILE")`. Quote all variable expansions. Hint: You can paste your script at shellcheck.net to find errors.

Comment: OK. I will write this with more details as an answer which you can accept.

Comment: No it was really useful, solved my problem. Worked great no need to rewrite it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Writing an answer marks this question as answered in the search and makes it more useful for others that may find it using the search function. The search function also shows if a question has an accepted answer, so accepting an answer shows that a solution for the problem was found.

Answer (score 0):

The script line

```
OUT=$(basename $FILE) kraken2 --db path/to/16S_SILVA138_k2db --threads 12 --use-names --gzip-compressed ${FILE} --output path/to/output/directory/${OUT}_kraken.txt --report path/to/output/directory/${OUT}_report.txt
```

will set the variable `OUT` only for the `kraken2` process, but not for the variable expansion inside the same line.

Writing the assignmant as a separate line will make it available for the variable expansion.

```
OUT=$(basename $FILE) 
kraken2 --db path/to/16S_SILVA138_k2db --threads 12 --use-names --gzip-compressed ${FILE} --output path/to/output/directory/${OUT}_kraken.txt --report path/to/output/directory/${OUT}_report.txt
```